# Why "NOT IN" does not work in this NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

`A`.`b` and `B`.`a` are inverse to-many relationships. Why does this predicate for `A` work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@", bObject.a];
```

while this one does not:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT %@ IN b", bObject];
```

I think both predicates should give the same result — the collection of `A`s that have no relation with `bObject` via `a<-->b`. But in fact, the first one gives the correct collection while the second one not.

Update:

---

Here is a [sample project](http://d.pr/TaA3) wherein `A`.`b` is embodied by `Account`.`filtered_clients` and `B`.`a` is embodied by `Client`.`filtered_by`.

Toggle commenting of line 143 and line 144 in `MasterViewController.m` to see the difference.

Please help me either find the bug in my code, or confirm it is a `Core Data` bug so I can report it to Apple. Thanks very much.

Comment: Your second predicate seems to be testing if b is not in b - is that what you meant?

Comment: As Nick pointed out: Can you give a bit more code. What is the `b` variable? How are are generating the fetch request?

Comment: To be more clear, I've changed the variable name to "bObject" which is an instance of B.

Comment: _A.b and B.a are inverse to-many relationships._ This suggests that b <<-->> a is many-to-many - correct?

Comment: Hey guys, I've created a sample project. Please read the update in question.

Comment: Looks like Core Data bug to me.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with Core Data, but i have been trying a lot of different predicates on a similar problem and could not understand why i do not get any results. Then I saw this question and i tried the inverse NOT SELF IN... and it worked.

Comment: sadly I still encounter the same issue as of today.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another idea: maybe it is trying to "negate" the `bObject` with the `NOT`. Thus, try:

```
@"NOT (%@ IN b)"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Important You must define many-to-many relationships in both
>   directions—that is, you must specify two relationships, each being the
>   inverse of the other. You can’t just define a to-many relationship in
>   one direction and try to use it as a many-to-many. If you do, you will
>   end up with referential integrity problems.

So check this:

1. A has a to many relationship to B.
2. B has a to many relationship to A.
3. The A relationship is the inverse of the B relationship.
4. The B relationship is the inverse of the A relationship.

Comment: Please read the question and the comments below it. It is, of course, a many-to-manty relationship.

Comment: I've created a sample project. Please read the update in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer for people coming across this question. Apparently you do need to use SELF for it to work, at least in my case with two to-many relations. This works for me:

```
NOT (SELF IN %@)
```