# NSFetchedResultsController loses his rows after entering background

Tags: ios, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've a strange problem in my app.

I instanciate a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate my array.

It's declared this way (as a `@propoerty (nonatomic, retain)` )

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedContactsController {
    if (self->fetchedContactsController != nil) return self->fetchedContactsController;

    // Create the fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // I want every contact...
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self->managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // ... whose are not associated with my order item
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%@ IN items)", self.orderItem];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate
    self.fetchedContactsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self->managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [firstnameSortDescriptor release];
    [lastnameSortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    // Execute the fetch request
    [self->fetchedContactsController performFetch:nil];
    return self->fetchedContactsController;
}
```

of course, contacts.items exists.

When my app goes background then foreground again, if I do another

```
NSLog(@"before >>> %d", [[fetchedContactsController fetchedObjects]count]); // >>> 3
[self->fetchedContactsController performFetch:nil];
[tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"after >>> %d", [[fetchedContactsController fetchedObjects]count]); // >>> 0
```

every line in my array disappear !

**EDIT :**

If I comment these lines :

```
    // ... whose are not associated with my order item
    //NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%@ IN items)", self.orderItem];
    //[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

The problem don't occur anymore ! But that's not what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it. [Thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9065711/127493), I replaced this line :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%@ IN items)", self.orderItem];
```

by

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@", self.orderItem.recipients];
```

It's funny how the fact you ask a question can make you on the path to resolve.